# How to compute differences of values in one column

Tags: oracle

```
C1 |C2 |C3
a  |b1 |1
a  |b2 |2
a  |b3 |3
a  |b4 |4
b  |b1 |5
b  |b2 |6
b  |b3 |10
b  |b4 |11
```

Given the  above table data, I want output like below:

```
C1 |DIFF
a  |3
b  |6
```

Here, `DIFF` is the difference of the `C3` column value, where `C2='b4'` and `C2='b1'`.
What would be the logic to do it in Oracle?

Comment: Are there always the same four values in `C2` for each distinct value in `C1`, or is it variable (eg. `b5`, `b6` and so on)?

Comment: @Engstrom yes C2 will be always b1 to b4 for each C1

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this...   `my_table` is your input table.

```
select t1.c1 as c1, t1.c3 - t2.c3 as diff
from   (select c1, c3 from my_table where c2 = 'b4') t1
       inner join
       (select c1, c3 from my_table where c2 = 'b1') t2
       on t1.c1 = t2.c1
;
```